# Report builder - using different queries according to parameter

Tags: sql-server, report, builder

I am trying to make a report, where I can select a multiple values from a parameter - and then make a query, where i state "where in (@partner)"

However, my problems occours, when I want to make a value, that will not do the "where in (@partner)", but will simply select all from the same query, without the where in clause - as not all rows in my db table, have the specific values set, so I want to catch them too.

All the values for the parameter is selected from a query, and I have a union on it, to create a value for the one, where I need to select all - not using the where in.

It actually works, if only one value from the parameter list is chosen - but as soon as I try to select 2 or more, I get the error "query execution failed for dataset1......"

The value of the parameter value, that is used for selecting all is 0, as you see in the code - and it does work as I can execute both select statements below, but not when I select more then 1 value from the parameter list.

```
IF @partner = 0
BEGIN
SELECT
thedata

FROM
thetable
WHERE
thedata = 3
END
ELSE
SELECT
thedata

FROM
thetable
WHERE
thedata = 3
and partner in (@partner)
END
ELSE
```

Hope there is some clever guys out there:) Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on that? First time hearing the frase dynamic sql

Comment: Can you do a profiler trace and post the SQL query that gets executed when you select two different parameter values?   Also, in your table, what is the datatype of the Partner column?

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
SELECT thedata
FROM thetable
WHERE thedata = 3 
AND (partner IN (@partner) or @partner = 0)
```

Comment: @user2199192 Are you sure that your parameter is multivalued one?, does the query work if you only use `WHERE thedata = 3  AND partner IN (@partner)`?

Comment: Yes it does, if I have no if and else just the pure statement, i can select multiple values and it works. The 0 I am using is not in the database though, that comes from a union on the query getting the param values, so I need some sort of if and else to do it I would think

Comment: And did you test the answer I posted alone?, I mean, no `IF`s

Comment: That doesn't make much sense, though. So, you are either selecting multiple values or selecting just `0`, right?, why can't you just select every value instead?

Comment: Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)

Comment: It can select one value, if I go beyond 1, i will get the error

Comment: I cant select every value - because not all entries in the db has a value to match up on, so I need to be able to select all from db, intead of when in (ids)

Comment: @user2199192 And that's your whole query, nothing else?, what is the datatype of `partner`?, and the parameter. And how did you set up the parameter?

Comment: The parameter is set up from a query, where I select all the ids of partners, and then a union to select 0 also as parameter value, to determine how to select all - and it is all just a bunch of numbers, as integers in the database. The datatype of @partner is array, when i ask reportbuilder IsArray(@partner) it return true

Comment: @user2199192 Man, I'm talking when you defined as multivalue, does it accept nulls, all of that.

Comment: Cant accepts null, when multiple values are accepted - the parameter is text, does accept multiple values, no empty strings or nulls

Comment: @user2199192 Sorry, but I can't help you. It *seems* like it should be correct, but can't say for sure

Comment: It all seems logical for me too, and I though it would work - but no - but thanks for your time:)

Comment: Thats weird, I tryed to set another parameter to yes or no, depending if I want all, or just the selected ones - that actually works, when selectiing all or multiple values...